# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=activity2.application1 (has extras) }

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to call activity2 of application1 from main activity of application2 on touching submit button which is hooked to submit function but I am getting this error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=activity2.application1 (has extras) }

I am running application1 before application2 so that application2 can find activity2 from application1.

Application2 MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.application2;

import com.example.application2.R;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void submit(View v){

    String s = "activity2.application1";
    Intent intent = new Intent(s);
    intent.putExtra("name",      ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("about", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("age", ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1)).getSelectedItem().toString());

    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Application1 activity2.java

```
package com.example.application1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activity2 extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    t1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"));

    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    t2.setText(intent.getStringExtra("age"));

    TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    t3.setText(intent.getStringExtra("about"));
}

}
```

Application1 AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.application1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"

 >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activity2">

        <intent-filter >

            <action android:name="activity2.application1">

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>


            </action>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity 1 is missing in manifest file. Add activity declaration in manifest file.

Inside application tag of manifest you can add new activity like:

---

```
<activity android:name=".newActivity"/>
```

Comment: there is no Activity 1 in my application.